# How to trim multiple file names using batch file

Tags: batch, filenames, batch-rename

I need to trim all file names in a folder on a daily basis and therefore am searching for batch file recommendations. Any help is much appreciated!!

The numbers behind the file names are changing on a daily basis...
Windows 10, all file extensions are csv.

Here some examples:

```
                              what it's now --> what it needs to look like
                           ---------------------------------------------------
ECOM_IN_ITEMATTRIBUTE_BRAND_20221020_133719 --> ECOM_IN_ITEMATTRIBUTE_BRAND
ECOM_IN_LINESORDERMIA_20221021_075153       --> ECOM_IN_LINESORDERMIA
ECOM_IN_MASTERFILE_20221020_130710          --> ECOM_IN_MASTERFILE
```

Comment: Which operating system do you use exactly? Are the file names without file extensions? Or are they different? Please [edit] your question and add some information.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a small PowerShell script combined with regular expressions (RegEx). Without or with a different file extension you have to adapt the back part for your needs.

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace '(_\d+_\d+)\.txt', '.txt' }
```

Use the `-WhatIf` parameter on `Rename-Item` to check renames in order to avoid a mistake.

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace '(_\d+_\d+)\.txt', '.txt' } -WhatIf
```

[image]

#### Further solution with graphical user interface

[Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) allows you to easily rename files and entire folders based upon extremely flexible criteria.

[Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer) is another free program that makes easier the renaming of lots of files and folders by using specified settings. It supports Unicode names.

Answer (score 0):

- For **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**, you can try:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*^delims^=2 %%i in =;(`2^>nul ^<con: dir /b /a:a "*_*_*.csv"
    `);= do set "_n=%%~ni%%~xj" && "%ComSpec%" /v /r "ren ".\%%~i2*%%~j" "!_n:_.=.!""
```

---

**Obs.:** If the batch is not in the same folder as the files to be renamed, replace:

```bat
cd /d "%~dp0"
:: with full path :: 
cd /d "D:\the\full\path\of\the\folder\where\the\files\are"
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Thanks to you for testing and commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [Bulk Rename Command Line](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php#DownloadBulkRenameCommand)

"D:\Program Files\Bulk Rename Utility\BRC64.exe" /removelastn:16

```
Processing Folder G:\HB\
Filename ECOM_IN_ITEMATTRIBUTE_BRAND_20221020_133719.txt would be renamed to ECOM_IN_ITEMATTRIBUTE_BRAND.txt
Filename ECOM_IN_LINESORDERMIA_20221021_075153.txt would be renamed to ECOM_IN_LINESORDERMIA.txt
Filename ECOM_IN_MASTERFILE_20221020_130710.txt would be renamed to ECOM_IN_MASTERFILE.txt
```

"D:\Program Files\Bulk Rename Utility\BRC64.exe" /removelastn:16 /execute

```
Processing Folder G:\HB\
Filename ECOM_IN_ITEMATTRIBUTE_BRAND_20221020_133719.txt renamed to ECOM_IN_ITEMATTRIBUTE_BRAND.txt
Filename ECOM_IN_LINESORDERMIA_20221021_075153.txt renamed to ECOM_IN_LINESORDERMIA.txt
Filename ECOM_IN_MASTERFILE_20221020_130710.txt renamed to ECOM_IN_MASTERFILE.txt
```