# Windows Batch Command to Rename a File

Tags: batch, rename

I have a file named:
`ORA_GL_2023-09-19_12-36-47.TXT`
That needs to be renamed to:
`ORA_GL_2023-09.TXT`

I tried

```
REN ORA*.TXT REN ORA_GL_????-??.TXT
```

without success.

Greatly appreciate assistance on this!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1748716/how-to-trim-multiple-file-names-using-batch-file

Comment: If you just want to rename one file, type `ren oldname newname` and it will work. If you want to batch rename multiple files, we'll need more info, but its probably easier to use a program that can do batch renames with patterns. Batch scripting is not that powerfull, and PowerShell might be too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder"

for /f ^tokens^=1-3*^ ^delims^=^- %%i in =;('
    dir /a:a /b "*_*_*-*-*_*-*-*.txt" 2^>nul'
    );= do if not exist .\"%%~i-%%~j%%~xl" =;( 
        rename .\"%%~i-%%~j-%%~k-%%~l". "%%~i-%%~j%%~xl".
        );= else echo/Duplicated: "%%~i-%%~j-%%~k-%%~l" "%%~i-%%~j%%~xl".
```

---

You need to use a `For /F` loop and treat the occurrences according to the delimiters to filter the files of interest and model the destination layout for the new name, in addition, when applying a "crop" to the new name, you will must avoid having files with occurrences of duplicity.

---

---

**Additional Resources:**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`if /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)